# Do parentheses prevent semicolon insertion?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks, automatic-semicolon-insertion

Say that I want to set a bunch of variables equal to null (and don't want to use an array/loop structure) or maybe I just want to write a large boolean expression across multiple lines. Does an unclosed parenthetical prevent semicolon insertion in such a case? E.g.

```
some_variable = another_variable = yet_another_variable = (
    oh_look_a_parenthesis_above_me = hey_heres_another_variable) = (
    and_for_some_reason_another = last_one) = null;
```

Or

```
if(test_for_some_complex_expr && another_test || (
    but_maybe_this_one && or_this_one)) {
    // ...
}
```

And how does this compare versus using `&&` or `||` or `=` to group expressions over line breaks? I.e., would this always work too?

```
some_variable = another_variable = 
    a_variable_after_a_line_break = and_one_more;

while(test_for_an_expr && another_test || 
    (an_expr_here && and_an_expr_here)) {
    // ...
}
```

I'm looking for the way that is most standard across all browsers (including IE6+).

Comment: AFAIK, JavaScript doesn't care about whitespace (making your concerns moot).

Comment: @Brad: JavaScript actually do care about line breaks in some cases.

Comment: @JacquesB: Only quoted strings and some logical situations, but I was referring more to elongating conditional expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semicolon insertion only happens if you have code which would be a syntax error without the semicolon. In your case the expression is perfectly valid, so you don't need to worry about semicolon insertion - parentheses or not.

An example where semicolon insertion will happen:

```
var a = 1
var b = 2
```

In the above case, a semicolon is inserted at the line break, but only because it is a syntax error to write:

```
var a = 1 var b = 2
```

but it is perfectly valid to write:

```
var a = 1; var b = 2
```

The rules get tricky because there are some instances in JavaScript syntax where line breaks are NOT allowed. For example a line break is NOT allowed between the '`return`' keyword and a value to return. So this is a syntax error:

```
return
  17;
```

But the way semicolon insertion "fixes" this error is by inserting a semicolon like this:

```
return;
  17;
```

Which is probably not what the writer intended!
In that particular case, a parenthesis can be used to prevent semicolon insertion:

```
return (
   17);
```

Because it only between the return keyword and the start of the expression that line break is disallowed. Inside an expression it is not a problem.

Comment: This was very insightful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Does an unclosed parenthetical prevent semicolon insertion in such a case?

Yes. Although it is unnecessary:

> And how does this compare versus using `&&` or `||` or `=` to group expressions over line breaks?

It's exactly the same. They are expressions that *require* a second part, therefore ASI cannot - must not - kick in without making the result invalid.

ASI will *only* occur when the continued line is *invalid* without the semicolon. See [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572) for details.